# /usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory

Tags: git, docker, newline, windows-subsystem-for-linux, core.autocrlf

I am having an issue after setting up docker in Linux terminal in win10.
When I am trying to build it shows following error.

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory
ERROR: Service 'magento2' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c /opt/docker/bin/service.d/autosync.sh install     && docker-service-enable autosync' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Is it git line ending bug and how can I solve it?

Comment: Git doesn't have a line ending bug. However, depending on your git settings, it might propagate Windows line endings into your Linux box. Read https://help.github.com/en/articles/dealing-with-line-endings (read both Linux and Windows page) to understand the issue to solve it long-term. Right now, it's easiest to use `dos2unix` and re-commit the file.

Comment: if i run this command from terminal "/bin/sh -c /opt/docker/bin/service.d/autosync.sh install" it says "install: 1: install: /opt/docker/bin/service.d/autosync.sh: not found"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it by finding that autosync.sh somewhere in my projects hidden and changed file format to Unix and boom it worked.

Answer (score 15):

In VSCODE you can use:
[VSCODE Editor Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6gDj.png)

LF can be changed in CRLF and back

Answer (score 2):

You get this error message simply because the `/dev` folder is not in `/bin`. It is directly in the `/flutter` folder so change your path this way solve this problem:

```sh
export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_TO_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/flutter"
```

Comment: This is not working for me. When doing it this way the dart executable can not be found, obviously.